# Combobox DropDownList style font mismatch

Tags: winforms, combobox

[image]

The text of the combobox is different than the items's font. Why and how can I fix it.

Comment: Is that the standard ComboBox component?  Are you using a third party skinning tool?

Comment: yes, its the standard one.

Comment: What I'm getting at, it seems like you need to document this question a little better.  What's the DrawMode, etc?

Comment: DrawMode is Normal, its just your default combobox with nothing set but the style and font.

Comment: This is interesting behavior . Would be interesting to see your properties on form and combobox. And to know your item datasource.